# Python: Trying to understand how `lambda`s interact with outer scopes

Tags: python, lambda, scope, bind

I've got the following examples:

1. `outer` is a variable defined outside the `lambda`. Changes to `outer` are seen by the `lambda`:

```
foo = lambda: outer
outer = 'outer'
print(outer) # 'outer'
print(foo()) # 'outer'

outer = 'changed'
print(outer) # 'changed'
print(foo()) # 'changed'
```

2. `outer` is still a variable defined outside the `lambda`. Changes to `outer` are still seen by the `lambda`, but if the change to `outer` is inside the `lambda`, then the change to `outer` is not seen by the outside scope:

```
foo = lambda: (outer := 'changed in lambda', print(outer))
outer = 'outer'
print(outer) # 'outer'
print(foo()) # 'changed in lambda'
print(outer) # 'outer'
```

3. The following are examples of when `lambda's` do and don't change an outer scope variable. Each example has a `def` function equivalent (with one caveat) which is also shown:

````
+---------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Example | `lambda` version                              | `def` version                        |    change of `outer`   |
|         |                                               |                                      | seen by outside scope? |
+=========+===============================================+======================================+========================+
|   3a.   | ```                                           | ```                                  |           no           |
|         | foo = lambda: \                               | def foo():                           |                        |
|         |   (outer := 'changed in lambda',              |   outer = 'changed in lambda'        |                        |
|         |   print(outer))                               |   print(outer)                       |                        |
|         | outer = 'outer'                               | outer = 'outer'                      |                        |
|         |                                               |                                      |                        |
|         | print(outer) # 'outer'                        | print(outer) # 'outer'               |                        |
|         | foo() # 'changed in lambda'                   | foo() # 'changed in lambda'          |                        |
|         | print(outer) # 'outer'                        | print(outer) # 'outer'               |                        |
|         | ```                                           | ```                                  |                        |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
|   3b.   | no `lambda` version because                   | ```                                  |           yes          |
|         | using `global` in a `lambda`                  | def foo():                           |                        |
|         | seems to be invalid syntax.                   |   global outer                       |                        |
|         |                                               |   outer = 'changed in lambda'        |                        |
|         |                                               |   print(outer)                       |                        |
|         |                                               | outer = 'outer'                      |                        |
|         |                                               |                                      |                        |
|         |                                               | print(outer) # 'outer'               |                        |
|         |                                               | foo() # 'changed in lambda'          |                        |
|         |                                               | print(outer) # 'changed in lambda'   |                        |
|         |                                               | ```                                  |                        |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
|   3c.   | ```                                           | ```                                  |            no          |
|         | foo = lambda: \                               | def foo():                           |                        |
|         |   (outer := ['changed in lambda'],            |   outer = ['changed in lambda']      |                        |
|         |   print(outer))                               |   print(outer)                       |                        |
|         | outer = ['outer']                             | outer = ['outer']                    |                        |
|         |                                               |                                      |                        |
|         | print(outer) # ['outer']                      | print(outer) # ['outer']             |                        |
|         | foo() # ['changed in lambda']                 | foo() # ['changed in lambda']        |                        |
|         | print(outer) # ['outer']                      | print(outer) # ['outer']             |                        |
|         | ```                                           | ```                                  |                        |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
|   3d.   | ```                                           | ```                                  |           yes          |
|         | foo = lambda: \                               | def foo()                            |                        |
|         |   (outer.__setitem__(0, 'changed in lambda'), |   outer[0] = 'changed in lambda'     |                        |
|         |   print(outer))                               |   print(outer)                       |                        |
|         | outer = ['outer']                             | outer = ['outer']                    |                        |
|         |                                               |                                      |                        |
|         | print(outer) # ['outer']                      | print(outer) # ['outer']             |                        |
|         | foo() # ['changed in lambda']                 | foo() # ['changed in lambda']        |                        |
|         | print(outer) # ['changed in lambda']          | print(outer) # ['changed in lambda'] |                        |
|         | ```                                           | ```                                  |                        |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
````

*Table created using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables*

---

Where can I learn more about the mechanics of `lambda`s and their scope?

[Python doc's definition of `lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lambda) goes some ways towards explaining this behavior (emphasis mine):

> An anonymous inline function consisting of a single expression which is **evaluated when the function is called**. The syntax to create a lambda function is `lambda [parameters]: expression`

Comment: Well, the TL;DR is that `:=` simply always assigns to a local variable inside the function and does not modify the outer variable. To modify the outer variable, you'd need to explicitly declare `global outer`, which is, as you say, invalid inside a lambda since it's a statement, and a lambda only takes an expression.

Comment: There is nothing specific to lambdas compared to normal functions, so the normal rules about local variables apply.